# Some Properties are not binding when used in ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, stackpanel

I have an ItemsControl element that populates a Stackpanel. Its bound to a ObservableCollections full of "LedModel" objects (see below).

I **cannot** get the binding for **Brush, Size and BlurRadius** to work.

Oddly enough however **the binding for the Label does work**...

```xml
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=Leds}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel
                Orientation="Vertical"
                IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse
                    Width="{Binding Size}"
                    Height="{Binding Size}"
                    Fill="{Binding Brush}">

                    <Ellipse.Effect>
                        <BlurEffect
                            Radius="{Binding BlurRadius}" />
                    </Ellipse.Effect>
                </Ellipse>

                <Label Content="{Binding ColorString}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```cs
public partial class LEDStack : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    // ...
    public ObservableCollection<LEDModel> Leds { get; }
    // ...
}
```

```cs
public class LEDModel {
    public string ColorString => GetColorString();
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; } = Brushes.Orange; //does not bind
    public double Size { get; set; } = 25d; // does not bind
    public double BlurRadius { get; set; } = 10d; // does not bind

    private string GetColorString() {
        return $"{Brush.Color.R}, {Brush.Color.G}, {Brush.Color.B}";
    }
}
```

It does not throw me any error or warning in IDE, during compile or at runtime.
My IDE also shows me the binding worked correctly and when inspecting the UI tree I see the stackpanel was properly populated (and I can see all the labels in my app)

Using Brush or Color instead of SolidColorBrush --> did not work

Using int or float for Size / BlurRadius --> did not work

Comment: everything works for me. problem is not in the presented code

Comment: Could you share your code? I can probably extrapolate my original issue from it

Answer (score -1):

Solution: I needed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in LedModel.cs to make modification of individual objects in the Collection be reflected in the UI